# Traceability Matrix Chart on Flex

Tags: apache-flex, matrix, charts, flex4, traceability

I need to generate a traceability matrix using FLEX 4. The closest thing i found was the plot chart, but it doesn't seem the right thing for me.

Is there any feature or framework that could help me? I checked out the axiis framework but i didn't find anything =/

Thank you and sorry for the bad english :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're feeling adventuresome you could implement this using the `DataGrid` control. I don't think there is a chart object that will give you this.

The first column would be your row titles and the cells would be ownerdraw.

Getting the first row to write vertically might be an issue but I'm sure it's been done somewhere.

Comment: `DataGrid` is really a painfull solution =/ I'll try it anyway

Comment: It's not just *that* bad. The only reason I suggested it as I've done it a few times.